TypeScript with Chakra UI what is the correct way to support StyleProps?
Getting an error on a parent component with the message of:

Type '{ bar: string; py: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
Property 'py' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.ts(2322)

parent component:
// striped code
export default async function parent() {
  const data = await apiLogic() 

  return (
    <Flex>
      <Child bar={data?.bar} py="6" />
    </Flex>
  )
}

child component:
interface Props {
  bar: string
  props: any
}

export default function Child({ bar, ...props }: Props) {
  return (
    <Box {...props}>
      // code stripped
    </Box>
  )
}

Research:

Property '...' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
Property does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes' with useFormContext and custom tag
React - Property does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes
Property does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Is there a special way when spreading props with TypeScript I should be implementing here? How can I resolve the error for Chakra UI StyledProps py?

Chakra UI exports prop types for each component, so your own custom interfaces can be extended with Chakra UI's props, including py. Since the component is destructuring out the custom props before spreading it into the Box, this should fix the Typescript warning.
Example for Box:
import { Box, type BoxProps, Flex, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react'

// Extend the exported prop interface for the Chakra UI component
interface CustomProps extends BoxProps {
  bar: string;
}

// Use the custom interface that extends Box props and destructure out your custom prop additions
export const Child = ({ bar, ...chakraProps }: CustomProps) => {
  // Pass the rest of the Chakra component props to Box
  return (
    <Box {...chakraProps}>
      <Text>{bar}</Text>
    </Box>
  )
}

export const Parent = () => {
  const data = { bar: 'foo' }

  return (
    <Flex>
      <Child bar={data.bar} py="6" />
    </Flex>
  )
}

export const App = () => {
  return <Parent />
}

CodeSandbox link
Note: Written when Chakra UI was version 2.8.2
